# Desktop PC turns on but doesn't boot. Video card Led on

Tags: boot, graphics-card, motherboard

My computer was randomly rebooting. I flashed the BIOS and it worked for a few months. Then it started again, but this time it rebooted and sometimes didn't come back. The fans and lights were on, but it just didn't POST.

It has done this a last time, and now it won't boot at all. I turn it on, all lights and fans are on, but there's no beep, no image from video card, nothing.

I have the following system:

- Asus P7P55D LE
- Intel Core i5 750
- Sapphire Radeon HD4850 1GB
- 2x2GB Patriot Viper II Sector 5, DDR3 1600 MHz
- OCZ Stealth X Stream 500SXS 500W

What tests I have done so far:

- Holding MemOK button for 30 seconds
- Unplugging the PC and holding the power button for 30 seconds
- Clearing CMOS by jumper
- Clearing CMOS by removing battery
- Testing both memory modules and slots individually
- Testing a different video card
- Testing a different PSU
- Testing the motherboard outside the case

None of the above worked, the results were the same. Then what I did:

- I tested the PSU with a voltage meter and all lines are within range.
- I tested the video card on another PC and it worked.

The video card has the D1601 led on, which indicates over temperature error, which could mean the video card is dead. However when I tested it on a different machine the led wasn't on and the card worked perfectly.

So, considering all these tests, I'm pretty sure the motherboard is dead. Is there anything else I could test to try and bring it back to life? Unfortunately the warranty has expired, so my only choices would be basically fixing it or buying a new one. Would it be worth fixing? The cost here is around 20% of a new card, but I've heard about people who fixed this board and it only worked for a few days before dying again.

If the only choice is buying a new one I will accept suggestions, because I don't know if I trust Asus enough to buy the same card again. I have done some research and this board seems prone to dying early.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The motherboard is dead, I just confirmed it. I replace the Asus P7P55D LE with a Gigabyte P55-USB3 and the computer is working perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem some months ago. My OCZ Stealth X Stream was broken. I tested it with an voltage meter and everything seemed fine, but it wasn't.
Mine made a clicking sound.

However, seeing that you've already tested a different PSU, it sure sounds like it's the motherboard ( or CPU ).

You could try to set up the computer without a case, and see whether that changes anything.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.

I have tested a 3rd PSU, just to be sure, and it still didn't boot, so I'm pretty sure that's not the problem.

I also had tested the PC outside the case, and it also didn't work. I added that info to the main post.

Thanks!